# Excel Print & Save macro file naming

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel document that a worker has to fill in the information. After that I made a macro that saves the file in 2 different folders and prints it. My problem is the naming of the file. How can I make it that it names the file for example

QualityReportN  where N is a number or exact date_time(with seconds)

here is the code so far:

```
`Sub PrintSave()
'
' PrintSave Macro
'
' Print on default printer save
' Save in two place:
'   1.Specific folder on desktop (named quality cards)
'   2.Network server (location eg. \\HOMEGROUP\QualityCards\)
'
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        "C:\Users\Logical\Desktop\EXEL\QualityReprotN.xlsx", FileFormat:= _
        xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
    ChDir "C:\Users\Logical\Desktop\New folder"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        "C:\Users\Logical\Desktop\Network\QualityReportN2.xlsx", FileFormat:= _
        xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
End Sub`
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Now()` function

```
Sub PrintSave()
'
' PrintSave Macro
'
' Print on default printer save
' Save in two place:
'   1.Specific folder on desktop (named quality cards)
'   2.Network server (location eg. \\HOMEGROUP\QualityCards\)
'
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        "C:\Users\Logical\Desktop\EXEL\QualityReprotN" & format(now(),"yyddmm_hhmmss") & ".xlsx", FileFormat:= _
        xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
    ChDir "C:\Users\Logical\Desktop\New folder"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        "C:\Users\Logical\Desktop\Network\QualityReportN2" & format(now(),"yyddmm_hhmmss") & ".xlsx", FileFormat:= _
        xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
End Sub
```

**EDIT:**

Check out the VBA Library for some other formatting! [Link](https://www.excel-pratique.com/en/vba_tricks/date_format.php)

Comment: Wow thank you this worked perfectly, also thx for the formats link very useful. I am able to make it as I want. ty a lot

Comment: Of course! Glad to help, if the answer was correct for you please mark as answered so this can be closed. Also, it might be good to have errors checks in your code in-case any of the locations may change, the "New Folder" kinda scares me a bit; maybe add a prompt to ask the user where the "New Folders" are just in case too?

Answer (score 0):

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        "C:\Users\Logical\Desktop\Network\QualityReportN" & format(now(),"yyddmm_hhmmss") & ".xlsx", FileFormat:= _
        xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
```